# Shopify App CLI Heroku -- page unresponsive

Tags: heroku, next.js, shopify-app, heroku-cli

I created my app with Shopify CLI "shopify create" (Node.js app) and deployed it to Heroku (shopify deploy). I already add my .env variables (scopes ,SHOPIFY_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_SECRET_KEY, host, shop) to my heroku config Vars, and I changed my app url to https://MY-URL.herokuapp.com/ , and the whitelisted redirect urls to https://MY-URL.herokuapp.com/auth/callback

When trying to open the app in my dev store, the interface is shown correctly (see image below)
[image]

However, the interface is unresponsive. So e.g. I can not press the button or select the text with mouse. (actually I can not do any mouse actions at all)

I have no idea what could cause this unresponsiveness.

Further info:

If i open https://MY-URL.herokuapp.com/  in browser, Safari says "Safari cant find the server, "https:undefined/admin/oauth/authorize?...",

Chrome says "

This site can’t be reached

Check if there is a typo in undefined.

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

I deployed the app a few hours ago (~4 hours) .

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?